# jQuery 3 dropdown menu - onChange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have three populated drop down menus. Each drop down menu is populated based on the choice of the previous selection. This means that the choices of "selector 2" are based on the choices of "selector 1", while the choices of "selector 3" are based on the choices of "selector 2". The drop down menu is populated dynamically using jquery, and the source is from a MySQL table.

When I select "selector 1", it populates "selector 2" and when I select "selector 2" it populates "selector 3". This works fine. The problem lies that if I have "selector 1", "selector 2" and "selector 3" selected, and I change "selector 1", the value of "selector 2" is lost (how it should be), but the value of "selector 3" is remaining there. I want the selector value of 3 to be reset when "selector 1" is changed and not retain the old value of the previous old selector.

This is my jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    function getTertiary(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_tertiary.php",
            data:'tertiary_cat='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#tertiary_cat").html(data);
            }
        });
    }


    function getSecondary(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_secondary.php",
            data:'primary_cat='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function selectPrimary(val) {
        $("#search-box").val(val);
        $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
    }
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="frmDronpDown">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Primary:</label><br/>
        <select name="primary_cat" id="primary_cat" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getSecondary(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select Primary</option>
            <?php
            foreach($results as $primaryCat) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $primaryCat["primary_cat"]; ?>"><?php echo $primaryCat["primary_cat"]; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Tertiary:</label><br/>
        <select name="secondary_cat" id="secondary_cat" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getTertiary(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select Seconary</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>State:</label><br/>
        <select name="tertiary_cat" id="tertiary_cat" class="demoInputBox">
            <option value="">Select Tertiary</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tried - to change

```
<select name="primary_cat" id="primary_cat" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getSecondary(this.value);">
```

to:

```
<select name="primary_cat" id="primary_cat" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getSecondary(this.value);getTertiary(this.value);">
```

I am getting this error in error_log

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: have you tried my solution.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Hi, I just tried it now and it worked - all lists are populating as they're suppose to. I have a new problem now. If I change the the first selection from the first selector, the second selector loses its value (as its supposed to be), though the third selector is keeping its value from the previous selection. I want it to lose its value and not keep it!

Comment: have you tried my answer, it'll solve your problem!

Comment: I tried `$("#tertiary_cat").empty;` as it seems cleaner in my opinion. I just tried it now it seems that it works.

Comment: $("#tertiary_cat").empty; will leave you with no options in the select list . where as $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select Tertiary</option>') will always have Select Tertiary option after you reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the value of the third DDown on Re stetting the second one like this :

```
function getSecondary(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_secondary.php",
        data:'primary_cat='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
             $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select Tertiary</option>')
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Might be value of  `$results` is not A array so add a check here will solve your problem**

```
 <?php
 if (is_array($results)){
    foreach($results as $primaryCat) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $primaryCat["primary_cat"]; ?>"><?php echo $primaryCat["primary_cat"]; ?></option>
        <?php
    }

 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change getSecondary to clear the 3rd drop down when primary is changed like this:

```
function getSecondary(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_secondary.php",
        data:'primary_cat='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
            $('#tertiary_cat').html('<option value="">Select Tertiary</option>')
        }
    });
}
```